# 4K on HDMI Port Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: xubuntu, hdmi, display-resolution, 19.04, 4k-monitor

I am trying to get the my laptop to spit out 4K resolution from the HDMI port to my TV. I am 90% sure my cable is HDMI 2.0 (it's been a while since I bought it, and just wayyy too many cables around the house). But when selecting the resolution in my settings the maximum option I get is of full HD on the drop down list. Is there any way to get it to go all the way? I am not sure what extra info I can provide, if you want to know something specific about my laptop specs please ask!

Comment: What is your graphics card and laptop make / model and CPU?

Comment: My laptop is an old HP laptop. I have an ATI 8670M. Processor is i5 3230M. I will post back on the exact model number!